# Function Doesnt return double value, it returns 0

Tags: java, return-value

Below is the function I am calling, but it returns 0 no matter what I pass.

```
public static Double calc(double methods, double attributes) {
    double a=0;
    for (int i=0;i<k;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<l;j++) {
        if(matrix[i][j]==1)
                a++;
        }
     }          
    Double v= new Double( a/(methods*attributes));
    System.out.println("The value of v = " + v.doubleValue() );
    return v.doubleValue();
}
```

The `System.out` statement prints correct value in function but return value prints 0.0.

Comment: Where are you calling this method from?

Comment: Why are you using `Double` at all? Can you produce a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem? (I suspect diagnostics failure...)

Comment: Have you forgot to pass `matrix` to function? if `a` is `0` it will be always `0`.

Comment: what is the value of k and l?

Comment: And why not you are returning v directly??

Comment: Well, firstly, you don't need to return `v.doubleValue()`.  This makes it perform some needless boxing and unboxing, since your return type is `Double`, not `double`.  Secondly, the code snippet you have here should work properly, so I suspect the error is wherever you are calling this method from. :)

Comment: rohit: I am callin it from main function.

Jon : I didnt get u, diagnostics failure means?

amitD: Matrix is public nd global

Comment: Please post your `main()` method.

Comment: am calling the function in this way from main: 

I have declare k and l as

public static int  k, l;
System.out.println("Value of v = " + calc((double)k,(double)l));

Comment: @user1755282 You should check Matrix element really  contains `1`. By default `int` arrays elements are initialized to `0`. You can do this by adding `System.out.println("Array Contents :"+ Arrays.deepToString(matrix));`

Comment: @Everyone, he says it prints the correct (non-zero) value inside of the method call.  The issue is obviously not with the matrix or anything inside of the method.  It has to do with how the value is handled wherever the method is called from.  @User, everything you've given us so far works fine.  You need to post the entirety of your `main()` method if you want any help.

Comment: @all: thanks a lot,  it worked now.
Problem was with the scope, my "v" variable was out of the function scope.

that was a silly mistake, but thanks a lot for those suggestions and quick response. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I took the loop out of your function (all it does is give a value to a). And I added a main (see below).

The return works fine. Maybe the problem is in how you use the return value?

```
public class Test {

    public static Double calc(double methods, double attributes) {

        double a=2.0;

        Double v= new Double( a/(methods*attributes));
        System.out.println("The value of v = " + v.doubleValue() );
        return v.doubleValue();

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {       
        Double x = calc(2.0,3.0);       
        System.out.println(x);  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run a demo :

```
public class demo1{
public static Double calc(double methods, double attributes) {
    double a=0;
    int k=2;
    int l=2;
    //int[][] matrix=new int[2][2];
    //int 
    int[][] matrix={{1,2},{2,1},{2,2},{2,2}};
    for (int i=0;i<k;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<l;j++) {
        if(matrix[i][j]==1)
                a++;
        }
     }          
    Double v= new Double( a/(methods*attributes));
    System.out.println("The value of v = " + v.doubleValue() );
    return v.doubleValue();

}

public static void main(String s[]){

Double x = calc(2.0,3.0);       
System.out.println(x);
}


}
```

Output is as follows:

```
The value of v = 0.3333333333333333

0.3333333333333333
```

So it is not returning 0.0.